# Different behavior between Desktop App and Service App

Tags: c#, .net, service, desktop-application

I´m having the weirdest problem.

In my C# solution, I have a desktop test application, and a service application. On the start of both applications, I call the exact same methods, and the behaviour is completely different.
My desktop application is working just fine, reads a COM port, process that info, and then inserts that data on my DB.
The service application, read the COM port fine, but then the processing of the data is completely different, and after that it throws an SQLException because it is trying to convert wrong data(Specifficaly a datetime '01/01/0001')

I need this application to be a Service, I´m having the desktop app just to test it. I´ve been working on services for a while and I´ve never seen this behavior before.

How is it possible that the application and the service work so different calling the same functions using the EXACT same libraries?.

Here is the code:

- Service:

  ```
  protected override void OnStart()
  {
                  csGPS.startGPSData();

      Thread hiloEscuchar = new Thread(delegate()
          {
              csListener listener = new csListener();
              listener.listenAutoCommand();
          });
      hiloEscuchar.Start();


      Thread hiloEnviar = new Thread(delegate()
          {
              csSender.buscarComandos();
          });
      hiloEnviar.Start();


      Thread hiloEnviarPosiciones = new Thread(delegate()
      {
          csSender.enviarPosiciones();
      });
      hiloEnviarPosiciones.Start();
  }
  ```
- Desktop App:

  ```
  private void btnComenzar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      csGPS.startGPSData();

      Thread hiloEscuchar = new Thread(delegate()
          {
              csListener listener = new csListener();
              listener.listenAutoCommand();
          });
      hiloEscuchar.Start();


      Thread hiloEnviar = new Thread(delegate()
          {
              csSender.buscarComandos();
          });
      hiloEnviar.Start();


      Thread hiloEnviarPosiciones = new Thread(delegate()
      {
          csSender.enviarPosiciones();
      });
      hiloEnviarPosiciones.Start();

      lblEstado.Text = "STARTED";
      btnComenzar.Enabled = false;

  }
  ```

I hope you guys can help me.

Thanks.

Comment: What does it mean that 'processing of the data is completely different'. Didn't you say that the code is the same? Can you mark the code where you notice the first differences?

Comment: The code you're showing us isn't really relevant. Somewhere in your methods, assumptions are being made about permissions or context that are not valid when running as a service. You will have to attach to the service and step through to see what is happening. You may also try running the service under your user account as a troubleshooting step to see if it works correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the code may be the same, services run under an entirely different security context. They usually run under the `LocalSystem` user, and have no access to the desktop. This use also has very limited network access.

You will need to debug your code as a service, or at least add some debug logging statements to try and figure out what behaves differently.

Comment: I think the problem might be the Regional Config. It is weird that my desktop application works fine, and my service don´t. Is it possible thar my service is working under a different regional configuration than my desktop app?

Comment: Yes, it is. Just log the current date and time with the default formatting and you'll see the difference.

Comment: +1 You led him to the answer but rather than comment and give you the check he posts an answer himself.

Comment: I resolved the problem before reading your answer, that´s why I posted the answer myself. That´s no newbie thing, It is just as happened... I think you are kind of desperate to answer... Anyway I´m very grateful for your help... it is not my intention to generate any problem... only to help and contribute to this great forum.

Answer (score 0):

'01/01/0001' is a valid .NET date but it is not a valid MS SQL date.

You might not be using MSSQL but any database will have valid date range.

DateTime on SQL is January 1, 1753, through December 31, 9999

SmallDateTIme is January 1, 1900, through June 6, 2079

I always check the date range prior to and insert.

Comment: Yes, I understand, I used that datetime example to explain what is happening. That is consecuence of my data not being procesed correctly. I do not have thar error on my desktop app.

Comment: Then isolate were the data value goes wrong and post that line of code.  Why are you trying to submit invalid data to the DB?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is resolved. For some reason, my service is using a different CultureInfo than my desktop application is using.

It seems that Desktop applications use the default CultureInfo, that is set on the Regional Configuration, and Service applications, for some reason, don´t.

Thanks you for your help.